# Passing BOOL * to ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: iphone, objective-c-blocks

Hi I need to pass a BOOL to the

```
ALAssetsLibrary 
- (void)enumerateGroupsWithTypes:(ALAssetsGroupType)types usingBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock)enumerationBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

enumeration block it has the following signature.

```
^( ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop )
```

and the documentation says:

Stop:: A pointer to a boolean value; set the value to YES to stop enumeration.

However if I try setting the value to

```
stop = YES
```

I get the following warning and the enumeration just continues.

```
Initialization makes pointer from integer without cast
```

So my question is how do i pass a boolean as a pointer to the stop parameter?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, `stop` is a pointer to a `BOOL` value. To assign a value to the memory location `stop` is pointing at, you have to dereference the pointer with the `*` operator. Like this:

```
*stop = YES;
```